# Error in processing entity WorkOrder unable to create entity object

Tags: infor-eam

I am receiving the following error calling GetAssetEquipmentOp:

"Error in processing entity WorkOrder unable to create entity object"

Here is the code so far:

```
public stringType getAssetDescription(string equipmentcode)
        {

            try
            {

                // Setup Service Objects
                MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.GetAssetEquipmentService getservice = new MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.GetAssetEquipmentService();
                MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001 getrequest = new MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001();
                MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001_Result getresult = new MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001_Result();

                // Setup Return Object
                stringType desc = new stringType();

                // Setup Service Parameters
                getrequest.ASSETID = new MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.EQUIPMENTID_Type();
                getrequest.ASSETID.EQUIPMENTCODE = equipmentcode;
                getrequest.ASSETID.ORGANIZATIONID = new MP0302_GetAssetEquipment_001.ORGANIZATIONID_Type();
                getrequest.ASSETID.ORGANIZATIONID.ORGANIZATIONCODE = _orgCodeBody;

                // Setup Datastream Object
                Datastream.EWS.Session sess = new Datastream.EWS.Session(_userid, _passwd, _orgCodeHead, _url, _tenant, false);

                // Prepare Service Request
                sess.PrepareServiceRequest(getservice);

                // Call Web Service and get result
                getresult = getservice.GetAssetEquipmentOp(getrequest);

                // Extract Description
                desc.stringValue = getresult.ResultData.AssetEquipment.ASSETID.DESCRIPTION;
                desc.errorNum = 0;

                // Close Up/Dispose
                sess.CompleteServiceRequest(getservice);
                sess.Dispose();

                // Return value
                return desc;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                stringType errorStringType = new stringType();
                errorStringType.errorNum = 1;
                errorStringType.errorDesc = ex.Message;
                return errorStringType;
            }

        }
```

I have checked the following:
- User group has interface permissions including BECONN
- User has "Connector" option selected
- User has status authorizations including * to Q for EVNT

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!  The problem was that the work order number did not exist.  It is a very misleading error but once an existing work order was tested, it fetched the work order with no issues.